# White rectangle error on ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My ActionBarSherlock works on android OS devices> = 4.0, but this error happens on older devices.
I searched the web for solutions, but found nothing.
Anyone know why this happens? How can I fix the problem?

Printscreen:

[image: screenshot of problem]

```
    <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<!-- Action Bar Theme -->
<style name="Theme.Test" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">    
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I think you forgot some background style variable in your themes/styles for older versions

Comment: I added the code of themes now

Comment: Resolved implementing ActionBarCompat